# What does "1e" mean?

Tags: c

I've seen some code online and I'm trying to work out what it is doing. In particular, I've never seen "1e" convention before.

```
time_t currentTime;
time(&currentTime);
uint64_t currentTime = (uint64_t)currentTime * 1e6;
```

Comment: Is it just me or would this code not compile? Pretty sure you have conflicting types for `currentTime` here

Answer (score 15):

That is 1e6, not le6, and it means 1 * 10^6 or 1000000.0

It is scientific notation.

Comment: Mr. Grayson is correct, though: it actually means "100000.0", not "100000".

Answer (score 6):

> I've seen some code online and I'm trying to work out what it is
>   doing. In particular, I've never seen "1e" convention before.

As others have mentioned, practically speaking, `1e6` is scientific notation for 10^6 which is 1000000 or better known as 1 million. But as has already been mentioned, by David, this is actually treated as a `double` in C and the value is actually `1000000.0`.

But I feel like these answers only focus on *that specific piece* of the code you provided and not the whole so I wanted to provide some additional context for you since you are trying to work out what the code is doing.

For these lines:

```
time_t currentTime;
time(&currentTime);
```

`time` takes a pointer `time_t` and operates on it, presumably writing some semblance of time to it.

The next line is actually illegal because `currentTime` was already declared so let's make a small modification:

```
uint64_t convertedTime = (uint64_t)currentTime * 1e6;
```

This line converts `time_t currentTime` to an unsigned 64-bit integer then multiplies it by `1e6` or `1000000.0`. This is likely being done for unit conversion. For instance, let's assume `time` wrote the time in microseconds (`1e-6`, 10^-6, or `.000001`) to `currentTime` so multiplying it by `1e6` will give you seconds. And I say that just because of what appears to be a unit conversion here not because I actually *know* what `time` did (i.e. I'm taking the code at face value here).

Comment: `uint64_t convertedTime = (uint64_t)currentTime * 1e6;` is weak code.  It can force `(uint64_t)currentTime` into a `double` and loose precision, only to multiply and convert back to `uint64_t`.

Answer (score 5):

In C, `1e6` has type `double` and its value is 1 times 10 raised to the 6th power.  It is equivalent to `1000000.0`.

Do not get fooled by the other answers: `1e6` does *not* mean the same thing as `1000000` in C, because `1e6` has type `double` while `1000000` will have some integer type.  There are big differences in behavior between floating-point types like `double` and integers types.

The syntax for writing numbers like `1e6` is defined in the "Floating constants" section of the [C11 specification](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf) (and earlier versions too).  It's kind of like [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation).

Comment: So it is not to be confused with the mathematical "e" (Euler's number: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant))? What if we had to use it?

Answer (score 1):

It's `1e6`

Scientific notation for `Math.pow(10, 6) == 1000000`

/* yes, you can do that with pretty much **any** standard programming language, including C */